# How to import a folder with "-" character on python?

Tags: python

I am having trouble importing a folder with the `-` character on Python 3.9. The structure is as follows:

```
folder/
   __init__.py
   utils_a.py
folder-utils/
   __init__.py
   utils_b.py
main.py
```

I need to import `folder-utils/utils_b.py` on `main.py`. The following code works for `folder.utils_a` but throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` on `folder-utils.utils_b`:

```py
from folder.utils_a import hello_world_from_a
from folder-utils.utils_b import hello_world_from_b
```

I have also tried to replace the `-` with a `_`, and did not work either:

```py
from folder.utils_a import hello_world_from_a
from folder_utils.utils_b import hello_world_from_b
```

I did not want to import with `importlib` or any other package, but I am failing to see how to declare the folder with `-`.

Comment: You simply cannot do that. Modules and packages have to have names that are valid Python identifiers.

Comment: That's... that's what you do though. "I want to import an invalid package without using `importlib`" is like saying "I want to add two numbers, but I don't want to use numbers to do it". It's contradictory.

Comment: Yeap, realized that after researching a little longer. Renamed the folder (it was a submodule, added it with an alias and everything worked fine :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` character is reserved in Python for arithmetic, and cannot be used in any variable, module, or library names. You'll have to rename any folder using a `-` character.

The folder name is invalid, its impossible to import the folder while it contains that character. You can't import an invalid folder/package with or without `importlib`.